# how ehcache determines "changed data"?

Tags: java, replication, ehcache

I believe ehcache replicates only changed data (delta)?

My question is how it computes the delta? Let's say I have a java object that has 5 attributes and out of which only one is changed. The class of this object only implements serializable.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are asking about Ehcache & Hibernate integration, then no deltas are sent. What happens is that Ehcache sends an invalidation event containing object cache key.

Then on the remote node this entry is flushed and re-loaded from the database again on the next request.

Comment: I am afraid the question has nothing to do with ehcache used as a level 2 cache in hibernate. It more about how distributed cache is implemented.